# How can I run `M-x compile` under a particular shell in emacs?

Tags: shell, emacs, compile

I've a piece of software that can only be compiled under `my-weird-sh`.  I like to use `some-better-sh` in my day-to-day work, so that is my login shell (via `chsh`).  This changes the shell in Emacs to `my-better-sh` which, normally, is all fine and dandy.  However, `some-better-sh` can't compile the software.

How can I change the shell for `compile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```lisp
(defun weird-compile () (interactive)
  (let ((shell-file-name "/bin/my-weird-sh"))
    (call-interactively #'compile)))
```

This will set `shell-file-name` locally when you call `weird-compile`, which you can bind to the key of your choice.